# Lisp format string for a list of an element and sub-lists

Tags: format, lisp

While I occasionally dream in Perl regex, the format specification for Common Lisp (CLisp) still leaves me slightly bewildered. I'm shooting for the following result:

Given a list `("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5))` I want:

```
| No Match| -2378 11  4| -2378 11  5|
```

out the other end. Here is what I get instead:

```
[685]> (fss sd)

("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5))
[686]> (format t "|~{~9<~a~>~2*~}~:*~{~*~{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}|" (fss sd))
| No Match| -2378 11  4
*** - There are not enough arguments left for this format directive.
      Current point in control string:
        "|~{~9<~a~>~2*~}~:*~{~*~{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}|"
                                           |
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [687]> :R1

[688]>
```

I'm delighted that I'm 2/3rds the way there, but the situation is driving me a little crazy. If I understand things correctly, the `|~{~9<~a~>~2*~}` consumes the first element of the list, `No Match`, and then skips the rest. The next portion, `~:*` resets the argument pointer back to the start of the list. Then the `~{~}` wrapper places me in the list. Next the `~*` skips the already handled portion of the list. The next pair of `~{~}` enters the first sub-list of the argument. The first sub-list is handled correctly. Then...ERROR. Clearly there is something amiss in my understanding of format, but I'm not clear on what that might be.

I've often felt that the rest of CL is pretty straight forward, but I really think we need a *'Format Cookbook'* chapter in the *CL Cookbook* at the very least.

In sum, this aspirant needs help from a more knowledgeable follower of the way. HELP!

Comment: Can you tell us explicitly how you want the output to be formatted, not just what current format string does?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Notice where I say given a list...I want: `| No Match| -2378 11  4| -2378 11  5|` That is the formatted result I'm looking for...

Comment: What I meant was that the numbers you've got in your format string are describing some field widths.  If the first element of the argument were `"Match"` instead of no match, you wouldn't want `| Match|...` (with one space between `|` and `Match`, but `|    Match|...` (with four spaces).  At the moment, we have to decipher the format string to learn this.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Ah! You are correct, I should have explained what I wanted more carefully. The first is a string element, either "No Match" or "Match" which I want right justified in a 9 character space. The sub-lists consist of 3 numbers with the first needing 6 spaces and the next two needing 3. This allows a one space pad between each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the third `~{`, you are entering element-wise printing of the first sublist.  Each iteration consumes three elements of the sublist, so it is done after a single pass.  Then, this loop is exited and the next higher loop goes to the next iteration.  It skips another element of the outer list (the second sublist), but then there are no arguments left to use for entering the inner loop again.

Instead of skipping forward and backward, you could simply use both the `:` and the `@` modifier of `~{` to process the remaining lists:

```
"|~{~9<~a~>~:@{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}|"
```

Comment: That results in `*** - -: ("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5)) is not a number` with the input of `(format t "|~{~9<~a~>~:@{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}|" (fss sl))`...

Comment: To quote Emily Latilla of long ago "Never Mind" your code works fine on `|~{~9<~a~>~:@{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}|" sl)` Note that (fss sl) != sl. Insert Homer-esq head slap here!

Comment: The aesthetic directive (`~A`) supports justification, so `~9<~a~>` can be replaced by `~9@A`.

Answer (score 5):

I constructed a solution incrementally.  Since the format string has only one argument, I started by creating a format string that prints each element of the list:

```
CL-USER> (format t "~{|~A~}|"
                 '("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5)))
|No Match|(-2378 11 4)|(-2378 11 5)|
```

Now, after the first element, we actually want to iterate over all the remaining arguments, which we can do with `~@{`.  I've added square brackets around each element so we can see the bounds of the iteration.

```
CL-USER> (format t "~{|~A ~@{[~A]~}~}|"
                 '("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5)))
|No Match [(-2378 11 4)][(-2378 11 5)]|
```

Now, each element *within* the list in the square bracket needs to be printed individually, since the field widths are not all the same.  We can replace the initial `~A` with `~9<~A~>` now, too.

```
CL-USER> (format t "~{|~9<~A~>~@{~{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}~}|"
                 '("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5)))
| No Match| -2378 11  4| -2378 11  5|
```

Now (and this is pointed out in another answer, too), the use of `~@` immediately followed by `~{` is a construct that can be replaced by `~:@{`, which shortens up the format string.

```
CL-USER> (format t "~{|~9<~A~>~:@{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}|"
                 '("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5)))
| No Match| -2378 11  4| -2378 11  5|
```

Finally, the [aesthetic directive, `~A`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cda.htm) can used to specify the field width.  `~mincolA` puts spaces on the right, but `~mincol@A` puts them on the left, so the use of `~<` is not necessary.  `~9<~A~>` becomes `~9@A`:

```
CL-USER> (format t "~{|~9@A~:@{|~6d~3d~3d~}~}|"
                 '("No Match" (-2378 11 4) (-2378 11 5)))
| No Match| -2378 11  4| -2378 11  5|
```

This sort of incremental approach can be used very frequently in Lisp to solve part of a problem first, and then refine the solution incrementally.  Unlike other languages that have a more expensive write-compile-run cycle, Lisp's quick REPL makes this kind of process very easy.

If you're going to do a lot of work with [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm#format), it's worth skimming through section [22.3 Formatted Output](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm) in the HyperSpec.  Most of the features you probably won't use for quite a while, but having skimmed through that section, they'll be in the back of your mind for when you need them.  (You'll have to consult the manual then, but the all to often underestimated point is that *you'll know that there's something in the manual, and where to look for it*.)

Comment: Similar to what I did to get as far as I did. I missed the `~@` which I shall now read up on!

Comment: The expanded answer is also deserving of a check mark but I didn't see it in time. :( Kudos to you both. Regarding the hyperspec, since I own both editions I seldom use it. That said I do have a .pdf of 22.3.3 with a indexed coversheet for the operators. Quite handy. Your advice is excellent (my quibbles aside :) )

Comment: I make lot of use of the HyperSpec, because Googling for "format hyperspec" is quicker than finding it in a hardcopy or even in a PDF.

Comment: @hsmyers Regardless of which version is accepted, do be aware of that `~9<~A~>` can be replaced by `~9@A`.  I added that in a later edit;  it wasn't present in my first final answer (heh).

Comment: Correct again :) As a biblioholic, you would have to pry my copy of CLSE2 out of my cold hands though. It is marked with stickies for all items of interest including format. That said, the problem is a typical one: you have to know at least a part of the answer in order to know just where to look. I should have found both `~@` and `~9@A` but my lack of experience forced a miss. I need to go back and re-read with the idea of "What can I use this for..." firmly in place.

Comment: @hsmyers Pray tell, where did you find a good copy of the ANSI spec?  Most of the [stories](http://symbo1ics.com/blog/?p=431) I've heard about it tell of receiving a (low-quality) photocopy made from a comb-bound, hole-punched, version.

Comment: If you mean the actual books, I bought those new when they were first published. If you mean the .pdf's I've got both editions, don't remember now where I got them. Would be happy to supply you with same given an email address. The copy of 22.3.3 is from www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node200.html. I first became interested in Lisp when 1.5 was current :) The MIT book was my first taste. Winston's book was my second. My first actual coding environment was MuLisp which I used to write a rational numbers package. Been doing this off and on for a long time...

Comment: @hsmyers I may have misunderstood which books you were talking about.  I've got mine own copy of CLtL2 (but I know that there are some differences between the book and the HyperSpec/ANSI spec), and I've read the SICP books.  My lab at university had copies of the Winston books.  Which did you mean by CLSE2?

Comment: Same one you did I think, 2nd edition of Steele's Common Lisp. Between the HyperSpec and CMU's version, I think I prefer CMU's. These days I've had to down size my collection of books so in many cases I've replaced them with digital versions. Still have a fondness for paper though :)